# How to use shortcut for "Jump to previous/next keyframe" while cursor is over 3d viewport?

Tags: shortcut

I set a shortcut for "Jump to previous/next keyframe", I used < and >

But this only works when my cursor is over the timeline. When my cursor is over the 3d viewport, the shortcut keys don't work, which is not what I want.

Comment: i understand your problem, but why don't you just use the up and down arrows which work in both views, if you do not change the default keys?

Comment: ah yes. So I had only changed the shortcut for the timeline specific "jump to next keyframe" button. I went into keymap preferences and changed them there, and now all good.